# Распознавание предметов камерой

Tags: java, android

Задание от ментора.

Андроид

Написать приложение, которое используя камеру телефона определяет объект который ты навел.  Т.е. твое приложение открывает камеру. Ты наводишь на предмет, оно в нотификации или еще как пишет предмет на который ты навел
Например наводишь на машину пишет что это машина

До этого написал только приложение, которое по кнопке выводит HelloWorld.
Посоветуйте что использовать, может алгоритм какой то подскажете, что почитать :)

Comment: Классный ментор. Я в андройде не силен от слова "совсем", но может он либу какую имел ввиду?

Comment: Не бывает глупых вопросов... (с) Я понимаю как это выглядит ) Я пол года пилил Java, а вчера первый раз открыл Android studio ) Можно конечно сходу месяца за два прочитать все, но сейчас нет времени )

Comment: На написание такого приложения опытной коммандой разработчиков уйдет большое количество времени. Для открывшего вчера Android Studio и полгода назад увидевшего Java это не решаемая задача, этот ментор хочет просто от вас избавиться под  нелепым предлогом ( Ха, он даже распознавание образов не может запилить, два дня уже в Android Studio). Cмотреть нужно в сторону нейронных сетей видимо.

Comment: Если делать это самому без привлечения дополнительных библиотек, то это действительно задача на нейронные сети. Но думаю, что вы неверно поняли задание и нужно просто задействовать какую-то существующую библиотеку. Советую это и уточнить у "ментора".

Answer (score 6):

Сходите на [Vuforia API](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk) - там есть распознавание образов - не уверен, что бесплатно, поскольку образ надо все равно засылать на сервер Vuforia, где он и обрабатывается.

Поройтесь еще здесь - [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) - также облачное распознавание.

Ну и на закуску соберите это приложение: [Android Object Detection](https://github.com/tzutalin/Android-Object-Detection) - и поройтесь в его исходниках - как он работает.

Answer (score 6):

Я видел пару статей, в которых делали приложение под андроид с распознавание объектов с помощью [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

Нашел одну из статей [Android TensorFlow Machine Learning Example](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tensorflow-machine-learning-example-ff0e9b2654cc#.5hkjvmi3a) и [исходники приложения](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/AndroidTensorFlowMachineLearningExample) к ней.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш вопрос звучит примерно так: "Я знаю, как перемножить 2 числа. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как доказать гипотезу Пуанкаре." Для начала, сделайте распознование рукописных цифр что ли (база данных MNIST). Вопрос слишком абстрактный. В текущей постановке задачи Вы никогда не решите проблему, так как даже не очерчен круг предметов, которые Вы хотите обнаруживать.

Если Вы хотите выделять машины в видео потоке, то можете почитать огромное количество статей на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/recognitor/blog/277781/). Но ещё раз подчёркну: если Вы берётесь за область, связанную с нечёткими задачами, множествами, машинным обучением, то Вам нужно начинать с простых задач, с решения примеров, а не с задач высокго класса сложности.

Comment: Я наверное не так вопрос задал ) Начнем с того - возможно ли это ? Если возможно - то какие средства использовать ?

Comment: Сейчас широко используются нейросети. Ваша задача непонятна. Что Вы хотите? Зачем Вам её решать?

Comment: Я хочу решить задачу которую дал ментор.

Comment: Нельзя распознать всё сразу на изображении. Вы можете очертить класс предметов, которые хотите определять. Вы скорее всего неверно поняли ментора. Либо я не понимаю Вас и Вашей задачи.

Answer (score 2):

"Ты наводишь на предмет, оно в нотификации или еще как пишет предмет на который ты навел"

В общем случае - нет, не реализовать :-) . Но вот распознавать конкретные классы объектов с хорошей долей вероятности в некоторых случаях реально.

Я бы посмотрел в следующие стороны :

- соответвующие api. Вроде имелись у IBM в его Watson, Google и Microsoft - и наверняка я перечислил не всех.
- (думаю, смартфоны не потянут, но - возможно - ошибаюсь) - ИНС, работающие как object detector-ы. Какие из них дают лучший результат я не скажу. Навскидку назову SSD (single shot multibox detector) и RCNN (вот тут могу ошибаться). Ну и как минимум - у первой - есть доступная "предобученная" конфигурация.

Ну и да - что до ИНС - возможно - сразу искал бы готовые реализации на tensorflow. Вроде у него есть версия для android.

з.ы. не то, чтобы я призывал копипастить, да и вообще был уверен в том, что это ваш случай - но - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android - TF_Classify вроде подходит под описание,